# $f$ convex: exists linear map $g$ s.t. $f\geq g$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be convex. Does there exist a linear map $g(y)=ay+b$ such that $f(y)\geq g(y)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$?

Clearly, if f is differentiable we can argue with the tangent line, but what if f isn't differentiable?

Comment: what are $x$ an $y$? Or better how are they quantified? Exists $x$? For every $y$?

Comment: As an aside, this is related to a generalisation of derivative for convex functions  called subdifferentials.

Comment: @copper.hat i'd say that's more than an aside!

Comment: @MichaelGrant: True, but getting into nonsmooth analysis would :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $x_0$, then there is an affine function $g(x) = ax+b$ such that
$f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ and $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x$. This is true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well.

The proof relies on a number of facts about convex sets. The proof below is
surprisingly technical for a geometrically obvious fact (of course, I may
be missing a much simpler proof that utilises the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

To see this, note that since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous, and so the epigraph $\operatorname{epi}f$ is a closed, convex set equal to the closure of its interior. The point
$(x_0, f(x_0)) \notin (\operatorname{epi}f)^\circ)$, hence the Hahn Banach
theorem shows that there is some linear functional $\gamma$ (on $\mathbb{R}^2$) that separates
$(x_0, f(x_0))$ and $(\operatorname{epi}f)^\circ)$.

This means that there is some $\alpha$ such that
$\gamma((x_0, f(x_0)) = \alpha$ and $\gamma((x,y)) >\alpha $ for all 
$y > f(x)$ (here I am using the fact that $(\operatorname{epi}f)^\circ) = \{ (x,y) | y > f(x) \}$). By taking limits, we see that
$\gamma((x,y)) \ge\alpha $ for all $(x,y) \in \operatorname{epi}f$.

Since $\gamma$ has the form $\gamma((x,y) = ax+by$, and
$\gamma((x_0, f(x_0)) = a x_0 + b f(x_0) < a x_0 + b y$ for all $y > f(x_0)$,
we see that $b >0$.

Furthermore, since $\gamma((x,y)) \ge \gamma((x_0, f(x_0))$ for all $x$,
we have $a x_0 + f(x_0) \le a x + b f(x)$ for all $x$.

Now let $g(x) = {a \over b} (x_0-x)+f(x_0)$, we see that $g(x_0) = f(x_0)$ and
it is straightforward to check that $g(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $b\in \mathbb {R}.$ Suppose $a<b<c.$ Let $s(a,b)$ be the slope of the line connecting $(a,f(a)),(b,f(b)).$ Similarly define $s(b,c).$ Key fact: $s(a,b)\le s(b,c).$ (Good to draw a picture.) Thus we can define

$$m_1 = \sup_{a<b}s(a,b),\,\, , m_2 = \inf_{b<c} s(b,c).$$

Both $m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb {R}$ and $m_1\le m_2.$ Let $m\in [m_1,m_2].$ Set $g(x) = f(a) + m(x-a).$ Obviously $g(a) = f(a).$ Suppose $c > b.$ Then $f(c) \ge g(c),$ simply because $s(b,c) \ge m.$ The same is true to the left of $b.$